# Calling promise a second time won't resolve

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following function. I built the function to be a `promise`. Now if I call `aboutMove().then(() => {..})` for the first time, everything works and it's being resolved. Somehow, **calling it somewhere else later for a second time**, the function will be executed, but **the `promise` not resolved**. How so?

```
export const aboutMove = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (didAboutMove && aboutAnimation) {
            aboutAnimation.reverse();
            didAboutMove = !didAboutMove;
            return;
        }
        didAboutMove = !didAboutMove;

        const about = document.querySelector('.about__container');
        const inner = document.querySelector('.about__inner');

        aboutAnimation = gsap.timeline({
            onComplete: () => {
                resolve()
            }, onReverseComplete: () => {
                resolve()
            }
        })
            .to(about, 1, {
                duration: 1,
                y: 0,
                ease: Power2.easeInOut,
            })
            .fromTo(inner, {
                opacity: 0,
                y: 500
            }, {
                duration: 0.8,
                opacity: 1,
                y: 0,
                ease: Power2.easeInOut
            }, 0.5)
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you add some more code, where are you calling it second time.
Also, if you can provide a codesandbox that replicates your problem it would be even better.

Comment: Because when you `return` in that `if` block, you never do resolve the promise.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the same `Promise`. You are creating a new one every time you call `aboutMove`.

Considering this code

```
if (didAboutMove && aboutAnimation) {
  aboutAnimation.reverse();
  didAboutMove = !didAboutMove;
  return;
}
```

if `didAboutMove` and `aboutAnimation` are both true you'll exit the promise intializer and **never** resolve the promise.

You most likely need to reset both flags before calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

When you call it for the second time, the `didAboutMove` flag will be true, and you enter the if block that simply returns without resolving the promise:

```
if (didAboutMove && aboutAnimation) {
    aboutAnimation.reverse();
    didAboutMove = !didAboutMove;
    return; // This is the problem
}
```

Therefore, you will need to resolve the promise, either by resolving or rejecting it. However, judging from your logic, you only intend to reverse the animation, so perhaps you don't need to return anything afterall.

Answer (score 0):

You are resolving your promise inside `onComplete` and `onReverseComplete` for `gsap.timeline`. Also, you are returning from the callback of Promise function based on  `didAboutMove && aboutAnimation` which is not scoped inside the function.
So, when you call the function for the first time. it sets the value for `didAboutMove` and `aboutAnimation` so on the next call resolve is not triggured. as the function returns before.

```
if (didAboutMove && aboutAnimation) {
   // This block will execute in second run.
    aboutAnimation.reverse();
    didAboutMove = !didAboutMove;
    return; // Returns from here in second run.
}
didAboutMove = !didAboutMove; // assigned truthy value on first run
aboutAnimation = gsap.timeline // assigned truthy value on first run
```